# Excel doesn't use the tab-character in a txt-file

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I drag txt-files with strings and \t characters into my excel-sheet, excel can't handle the \t. Instead I have to type the tab-button in the txt-file. Why \t doesn't work?

Comment: Off-topic? Can you please explain why?

Comment: Off topic as this relates at most to (super) user the way the quesiton is phrased now. The question has nothing to do with programming as it stands.

Comment: Excel wont understand what `\t` means, you'll have to either manually replace them all with real tabs (or another delimiter) or create a macro to do a custom text-to-columns. The standard text-to-columns will not accept a 2 character delimiter (through the gui at least).